# GUI not updating as expected/control flow issue

Tags: java, swing, sockets, concurrency, event-dispatch-thread

I'm making a networked Battleship game for a school project. The GUI features a grid of  `JButtons` that serves as the game board. When the user clicks a button, it calls the `sendShot()` method below. This method sends their shot to the remote machine, which checks if its a hit or a miss and returns the result. The first machine then receives that result and updates its GUI accordingly. The code I have below is doing this, but I the problem is that the GUI is not being updated until after the other machine sends their next shot. I'm guessing this is because I'm calling `recieveShot()` from within the `sendShot()` method, but I'm not 100% clear on why, since the method for updating the GUI (`gp.ob.updateBoard(sr))`) is called before `receiveShot()`. What am I misunderstanding here?

Further, I have a feeling that my basic program-flow method here is flawed, and that `receiveShot()` should not be called from the `sendShot()` method. Are there any obvious alternatives to this scheme?

```
void sendShot(ShotAttempt sa){

    try {
       oos.writeObject(sa);
       oos.flush();
       System.out.println("shot fired");
       ShotResult sr = (ShotResult)ois.readObject();
       gp.ob.updateBoard(sr); 
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.printStackTrace());}
      receiveShot();
}

void receiveShot(){
    try{
    ShotAttempt sa = (ShotAttempt)ois.readObject();
    ShotResult sr = gp.db.acceptShot(sa);
    oos.writeObject(sr);
    oos.flush();
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Comment: This may not have anything to do with it, but you're reading the `ShotResult` twice from the stream...once in `sendShot` and once again in `recieveShot`.  Also, we might need to see more of the code before we can deduce the overall problem...

Comment: can you please paste the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for quick help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the GUI is not being updated until after the other machine sends their next shot. I'm guessing this is because I'm calling recieveShot() from within the sendShot() method, but I'm not 100% clear on why, since the method for updating the GUI (gp.ob.updateBoard(sr))) is called before receiveShot().

The `receiveShot()` method blocks the Swing event dispatch thread or EDT. Since this thread is responsible for all Swing graphics, user interactions, and Swing event processing, none the Runnables queued on the event Thread and awaiting processing will be processed, even if they were queued before the `receiveShot()` method was called. They can only be processed when the thread is unblocked, which will be after you've received a shot.

Suggestions:

- You should do all your socket communication on background threads.
- I would create program states, perhaps held by an enum, say called State, and give it at least two possible values, SHOOTING AND RECEIVING.
- Set your State appropriately after sending a shot to be State.RECEIVING.
- Set back to State.SHOOTING after receiving a shot.
- Don't allow the player to send a shot while in the receiving state. This way your code won't require a blocking method to prevent the user from shooting.
- You could also have an END_GAME as one of your states.
- I would give my class a `setState(State state)` method.
- In this method, I could enable/disable my shooting buttons depending on the new state.
- You would need one background thread, probably a SwingWorker, running continuously, listening on the socket for messages. When this thread receives info that it has been shot, it then update's the program's state by calling `setState(newState)`.
- I would take care to call setState on the Swing event thread so that state changes are all done by one thread only.
- I would then call shoot on a separate background thread, but one that only exists to do the shooting. It would not be continuously running.

For more information on the Swing Event Dispatch Thread, please have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to wrap my head around what you suggested: So when would the state get checked?

Comment: @user2356560: You could check the state whenever the user tries to shoot, when he presses a button. If the state isn't State.SHOOTING, then the button press does nothing. Alternatively, you could listen for the State to change, and if the state isn't State.SHOOTING, you could disable the buttons via `setEnabled(false)` and visa versa when the state changes back.

Comment: `"Alternatively, you could listen for the State to change"` How do I listen for state changes? What construct can I use?

Comment: Are we talking about concurrency/synchronization here, because this is a topic I'm just familiarizing myself with...

Comment: @user2356560: concurrency principles would be involved. I don't think that you'd need to use any synchronized blocks, but would need to take care that all Swing code is done on the Swing thread. Again, please look at the link at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @user2356560: glad you did! Can you fill us in on how you achieved this?